# iis8 detailed error logging to file

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I can get Detailed Error logging to screen (local/remote etc). But what I really want is to log "Detailed Error" to *file*.

Does this exist?

I checked all the documentation that I can find, and for the life of me i can't see how to do this.

I don't understand why this wouldn't be a requested feature - something that sits halfway between "no logs" and processor-intensive "failed request tracing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with asp.net and want a drop in "write my errors to a log file" without making code changes, take a look at [elmah](https://elmah.github.io/)

The "pure" IIS solution is [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85).